# Kentico 11 Continuous Integration Fails to serialize report object

Tags: serialization, continuous-integration, filepath, kentico

We are attempting to serialize objects after enabling continuous integration and the process fails at a report and returns the attached error. This is a brand new blank azure portal site that has had almost no changes. We are attempting the setup for shared development between a team of 4 developers using their local machines and SQL express to develop and then migrate the site to Azure using VSTS source control.

```
Message: Serialization of object type "Report graph" (reporting.reportgraph) failed for object "graph" (GraphID: 1881). See inner exception for further details.

Exception type: CMS.ContinuousIntegration.ObjectTypeSerializationException
Stack trace: 
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.StoreSingleObjectTypeObject(FileSystemStoreJob storeJob, ObjectTypeInfo typeInfo, String objectType, BaseInfo info, Int32 counter, Int32 total)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(BaseInfo info)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractFileSystemJob.CancellableForEach[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`2 action)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractFileSystemJob.CancellableForEach[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`1 action)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.StoreAllObjectTypeObjects(String objectType, Int32 counter, Int32 total)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractFileSystemJob.CancellableForEach[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`2 action)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.StoreObjects()
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.RunInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractFileSystemAllJob.Run(Nullable`1 cancellationToken)

Message: Serialization of the object CMS.Reporting.ReportGraphInfo (reporting.reportgraph) - graph has failed.

Exception type: CMS.ContinuousIntegration.ObjectSerializationException
Stack trace: 
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractSingleObjectJob.Run(BaseInfo baseInfo)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.FileSystemStoreAllJob.StoreSingleObjectTypeObject(FileSystemStoreJob storeJob, ObjectTypeInfo typeInfo, String objectType, BaseInfo info, Int32 counter, Int32 total)

Message: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Exception type: System.IO.PathTooLongException
Stack trace: 
   at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at CMS.AzureStorage.FileStream.InitFileStream()
   at CMS.AzureStorage.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, IDateTimeNowService dateTimeNowService)
   at CMS.AzureStorage.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at CMS.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.FileSystemWriter.GetFileCryptoStream(String relativePath, HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.FileSystemWriter.StoreToFile(String relativePath, Action`1 fileStreamWriteAction)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.Internal.AbstractSingleObjectJob.Run(BaseInfo baseInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

What location is your project running in? You are running out of characters for the path for the file.

I would suggest trying to move the solution closer to the root of the C:/.